# How to style Card in reactstrap vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, reactstrap

I'm trying to vertically align my Card components but they end up aligning horizontally. I've tried editing it in css, adding `Row` and `.col-sm-4`, but they're still aligned horizontally. Any help would be great at this point.

```
<Row>
  <Col sm="4">
    <Card>
      <CardBody>
        <CardTitle>Card Title</CardTitle>
        <CardSubtitle>Card Subtitle</CardSubtitle>
        <CardText>Card Text</CardText>
        <Button> A Button </Button>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  </Col>
</Row>
```

Comment: `I'm trying to vertically align my Card components but they end up aligning vertically` as I understand, you need it horizontally, right ? because without `grid` attribute define in `<Col>` its default behavior is vertically aligned.

Comment: haha yes, thank you for finding that typo. i've been on this problem for a bit, starting to lose it. i tried added grid, didn't work. i tried wrapping it in a `<Container>` and added `fluid`, that didn't work.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it is now useless, try to take a look at your parent component style. With your code alone in my editor, it rendered vertically as you want.

Comment: I got them to align vertically, but I added `<Row>` in groups of 3 `<Card>` components, however i'm only rendering them as i need, so if i need 15 cards, how am I gonna put 3 in a row and make them vertical?

Comment: congrats @chelk !